# Multithreading in React Native with node:worker_threads

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I have a WebGL ES application that renders at 60 FPS and has expensive functions that take a few milliseconds.

Is it safe to use `node:worker_threads` in the root `App.js` file like so?

```
import {
  Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData,
} from 'node:worker_threads';

export default function App() {
  return <div>my app</div>;
}

if (!isMainThread) {
  // Run expensive task here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not, not directly. You need to either "Nodeify" (such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify) the React-Native app or you need to provide a stub that emulates the worker_thread functionality of node.

In web browsers, there is the Web Worker API. RN uses JavaScriptCore which is Apple's JS engine, which is wrapped by React-Native's C libraries that emulate some APIs that a Web Browser or Node provides. Sadly it does not provide the same APIs as a Web Browser or Node exactly. I suggest you try some of the libraries on NPM. Many look pretty old, and its possible newer RN versions provide some similar functionality.

Consider https://reactnative.dev/docs/interactionmanager.html using RN's interaction manager to schedule your heavy process work.

I perused a few libraries on NPM, I'd suggest trying this library first https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads